# how to config nignx proxy root path to tomcat server but service static content directly at same time

Tags: nginx

i want   nginx to  service http://myhost.com/v2 staic content directly ,

but proxy  http://myhost.com/ to http://mytomcat:8080/

my config of /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
   location /v2/static {

    }

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
            proxy_set_header Host               $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
```

now , got HTTP ERROR 404 when accessing  http://myhost.com/ ,but http://mytomcat:8080/ is working,

any one can tell me how to config nginx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `port_in_redirect off;` Set your config exactly as below:

```
location / {   
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        port_in_redirect off;    
        proxy_redirect  off;
        proxy_set_header  Host  $http_host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Hope that helps